# Exclude a word in a string

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a regular expression in python where I need to extract the value of the exact match of the string

**For Example:**

```
record

LDL PRODUCTNAME 5.0,PRODUCTNAME 65.6,HDL PRODUCTNAME  34.1
```

Where I need only the value of PRODUCTNAME that has to be extracted(i.e, 65.6) and other parameters like LDL PRODUCTNAME and HDL PRODUCTNAME should not be extracted from the record.

But when i use the below regex to find the values of `CHOLESTROL` I'm getting all the `values(i.e, 5.0 65.6 34.1)` since it finds the match `CHOLESTEROL`.

```
Regex: Value=^\(?!HDL\s|LDL\)(PRODUCTNAME\d{1}\.\d{1})+$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`:

```
s = 'LDL PRODUCTNAME 5.0,PRODUCTNAME 65.6,HDL PRODUCTNAME 34.1'

params = dict([item.rsplit(' ', 1) for item in s.split(',')])
print params.get('PRODUCTNAME')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
/,PRODUCTNAME (\d+(?:\.\d+)?),/
```

Comment: It still produces same result.

Comment: What? with the leading ","? `LDL PRODUCTNAME` cannot match (unless the "," is some special char in python. then you need to escape it)

Comment: it is asked a python answer

Answer (score 0):

With the following approach you are able to extract the *number* parameter of the certain product with or without preceded prefix `(LDL|HDL)`:

```
drug_str = 'LDL CHOLESTEROL 5.0,DIMEDROL 65.6,HDL SEMISTEROL 34.1'
search_drug = 'DIMEDROL'
result = re.search(r'(LDL|HDL)?\s?'+ re.escape(search_drug) + r' ([\d.]+)\b', drug_str)

print(result.group(2))
```

The output:

```
65.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

```
import re
strg = 'LDL PRODUCTNAME 5.0,PRODUCTNAME 65.6,HDL PRODUCTNAME 34.1'
match = re.findall(r'((?!PRODUCTNAME\s)\d*\.\d*(?!,)?)', strg)

print ','.join(match)
```

or

```
import re
strg = 'LDL PRODUCTNAME 5.0,PRODUCTNAME 65.6,HDL PRODUCTNAME 34.1'
Productname = 'PRODUCTNAME'
match = re.findall(r'' + re.escape(Productname) + ' (\d*\.\d*(?!,)?)', strg)
output = ','.join(match)
print "{} = {}".format(Productname,output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
drug_str = 'LDL CHOLESTEROL 5.0,DIMEDROL 65.6,HDL SEMISTEROL 34.1'
search_drug = 'DIMEDROL'
result = re.search(re.escape(search_drug) + r' ([\d.]+)\b', drug_str)
result.group(1)
```